# How to send Bearer authorization token using Spring Boot and @FeignClient

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, wit.ai, feign

I am using Spring Boot to write an application that interacts with HTTP rest servers. One of the servers I'm connecting to (Wit.ai) uses a beaerer authorization token. A curl request that yields a successful response looks like this:

```
GET /message?q=sample message HTTP/1.1
Host: api.wit.ai
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 526c3a11-8e61-4552-aa19-e913f6473753
```

The wit.ai docs say the following about the token,

> Wit.ai uses OAuth2 as an authorization layer. As such, every API request must contain an Authorize HTTP header with a token
>   Access tokens are app specific.

I am trying to send a GET request to this endpoint in a Spring Boot app using @FeignClient. However I the endpoint doesn't seem to be accepting my authorization token.
Here is my FeignClient code

```
@FeignClient(name="witGetter", url = "${wit.url}")
    public interface WitGetter {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/message?v=20180507q={text}",
            headers = {"Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX"})
        WitResponse getWitResponse(@PathVariable("text") final String text);
}
```

What is the proper way to pass such an authorization token? I have tried a few other things but to no avail. Thanks for any advice!!!

By the way, the following code works using a traditional Feign interface, but I need to use @FeignClient in this case.

```
public interface WitGetter {
    @Headers("Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    @RequestLine("GET /message?q={text}")
    WitResponse getWitResponse(@Param("text") String text);
}
```

(code below is in a separate config file)

```
@Bean
    public WitGetter defaultWitGetter(@Value("https://api.wit.ai") final String witUrl){
        return Feign.builder().decoder(new GsonDecoder()).target(WitGetter.class, witUrl);
```

}

**EDIT**

The error code I get when using the above code is:

> Exception in thread "main" feign.FeignException: status 400 reading WitGetter#getWitResponse(String,String); content:
>   {
>     "error" : "Bad auth, check token/params",
>     "code" : "no-auth"
>   }

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When using Feign via Spring Cloud, you can use it as you would define a standard Spring MVC controller.

Please check my article here about passing headers with Feign:
https://arnoldgalovics.com/passing-headers-with-spring-cloud-feign/

Quick hint: you can add a `@RequestHeader("Authorization") String bearerToken` parameter to the method definition.

And then of course call it like `client.method(..., "Bearer " + token)`

Comment: I want to have this `bearerToken` to be fetched from `application properties` file. I have them constant for a a Proxy Interface but variable across production & staging environments. What would be the best way to do that? The Feign Proxy Interface wouldn't let me use `@Value` and I do not want to hard code this token in my code

Comment: Is there a way to make this posible using filters? Just to do it in one simple filter and not to every request from the feign client..

Comment: @CarlosCruz yes, refer this one: https://arnoldgalovics.com/customizing-each-request-with-spring-cloud-feign/

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.demo.web;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.entities.CustomerDto;
import com.example.demo.feign.CustomerRestClient;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("customers")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ClientRestController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRestClient customerRestClient;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<CustomerDto> getAllCustomers(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        return customerRestClient.listCustomes(authorizationHeader);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

import com.example.demo.entities.CustomerDto;

import feign.Headers;



@FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:8085/customers",value ="customer-rest-client")
@Headers("Authorization: {token}")
public interface CustomerRestClient {
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<CustomerDto> listCustomes(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
}
```

[image]