# OAuth2 ,feign client,spring boot,401 null

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, feign

I am using oauth2 for authorisation in my spring boot app but when I want to access data  from one microservice to other microservice by feign client it give exception access denied 401 null

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Already Answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237709/how-to-send-bearer-authorization-token-using-spring-boot-and-feignclient